# How do I get past 97% Campaign completion?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have completed the Campaign on every level and located every piece of Intel but I only show 97% complete. I have even replayed the Campaign several times and it still won't budge past 97%. What am I missing or is it even worth worrying about?

Comment: What game is this?  I'm confused.

Comment: Given the way he has capitalized "Campaign", could that be the name of the game?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_(video_game)?  I echo your sentiment regardless.

Comment: @agent86 This was originally posted as an answer on a Modern Warfare 3 question, so maybe that is the game the OP means?

Comment: Look in your stats.  What does it say you have completed?

Comment: What you need to do is complete 3% more.

Answer (score 2):

I played through the MW3 campaign on veteran, after which it said my completion was 97.something percent complete. I then replayed and collected ALL of the hidden intel items in the game bringing my completion percentage up to 101.1%. Maybe this will work for you!

Answer (score -1):

I have reason to believe that it's just a minor glitch or cloak for what the real result may be, mainly because I have the same "situation".

My Campaign stats are at 101.9%, and it's been like that for a few months now. Nothing seems to be able to change that. And before anyone decides to criticize, NO I did NOT look up any ways to fix or relate to this problem, I just used my own primary experience.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with Steam?

Comment: Oh, you've got it on Steam? For me it happens on the X-box 360. :O

Comment: Yes, it's Steam/PC platform. It wasn't my decision for Steam. I ordered the game from NewEgg and it installed itself with Steam. I also have some stagnant data progress in 'Black Ops: Combat Training' that haven't budged for months. Maybe I should ask Steam support? I have had to recover from a 'System Image' several times when one of my SSDs failed and this might have caused a problem with my Steam account.

Comment: Well if that's the case, then checking with support would be a good start for sure! I myself am probably going to have to deal with my current Campaign statistics, but it shouldn't bother me too much, I suppose. :P I hope things become clear in the future for ya!

Comment: I guess it's not worth worrying about anyway. It's definitely not wasting my time or cell minutes on. I thought someone here might know the answer since it came up on a Google search. This is the last post I'll make since this site is a genuine PITA to log into. Every time I log in using Steam, I have to wait for e-mail with a code because Steam has detected that this is a 'new or different PC or browser'. Same PC, same browser, same PITA. Thanks for the help.